# How to call ajax again when user click back button to go back last webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Below is my code..

HTML Code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
    <div class="dropdown_div">
        <select id="q_type" class="dropdown" onchange="getSubject(this.value)">
            <option>Question1</option>
            <option>Question2</option>  
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown_div">
        <select id="q_subject" class="dropdown">
            <option>Subject1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
function getSubject(val){

  $("option", $("#q_subject")).remove();
  var option = "<option>Subject</option>";
  $("#q_subject").append(option);

    $.ajax({
      url: "api.path",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {id: id},
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
                    alert("Hi");
          $("option", $("#q_subject")).remove();
          var option = "<option>Subject1</option>"; 
          option += "<option value=1234>Subject2</option>"; 
          $("#q_subject").append(option); 
      }
    });
}
```

How do I use pushState into my code and let user can click back button to return last page and then still see the ajax data?

Comment: I'm not clear with your problem?....You want to see the ajax data on the previous web page??

Comment: Yes, Sorry for bad english.

Comment: You can store your ajax response in localstorage and fetch stored data in the next page..

Comment: thanks but any hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should save data received from ajax request to browser [`local storage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). Afterwards, in order to show ajax result when browser "back" button was fired, you should bind statements that you are calling in `ajax.success()` method to window [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) event. To omit code duplication, it`s better to use a declared function instead of anonymous one.

```
function success(response) {
    alert("Hi");
    $("option", $("#q_subject")).remove();
    var option = "<option>Subject1</option>"; 
    option += "<option value=1234>Subject2</option>"; 
    $("#q_subject").append(option); 
}
```

Save data to `localstorage` and call `success` function:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "api.path",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {id: id},
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
          localStorage.setItem("response", response);
          success(response);
      }
    });
```

Call `success()` when "back"  button was fired:

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
    var res = localStorage.getItem('response');         
    success(res);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rather suggest you to use sessionStorage which expires when the browser window is closed :)

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "api.path",
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {id: id},
          async: true,
          cache: false,
          success: function(response) {
              sessionStorage.setItem("DataSaved", response);
              success(response);
          }
        });
```

And then

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
    var res = sessionStorage.getItem('DataSaved');         
    success(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using the local Storage or Session storage. You will also need to have a onload function callback, to check if there are any previous values that you stored in the local/session storage, if yes, then show that data in the select box.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this Back() issue when using Ajax to navigate an MVC-5 application from within a JavaScript generated diagram. All clicks in the diagram are handled by Ajax.

Above solutions do not replace the complete body, in the repaired cases a Back() would restore just the edit fields. In my case, I don't need that. I need to replace the entire page from the AJAX and **also** enable the Back button to return to my original diagram context.

I tried above solution to replace body, and I have to note, it would *only* trigger the window.pop event after

```
 history.pushState({}, '')
```

But when the event triggered and it uses Ajax to fill the body, my Javascript would not properly re-initialize the diagram page.

I decided to use another pattern, to circumvent the the window.pop event and avoid the back-issue. Below code will not return into the Ajax code context, but instead simply replace current page, processing the Ajax return information from the server (=Controller) as a redirect link, like

```
    var url = "/ProcessDiagram/MenuClick?command=" + idmenuparent+"_"+citem;  // my Ajax
    $.get(url,
        function (data) {
            window.location = data;  // Server returns a link, go for it !
            return true;             // Just return true after going to the link
        });
```

.. this will preserve the Back() context, because the browser will take care of things.

Controller side composes the redirect link, like

```
    public ActionResult MenuClick(string command)
    {
        List<string> sl = command.Split(new char[] {'_'}).ToList();
        var prId = int.Parse(sl[0].Substring(3));

        if (sl[1] == "PU")
            return Content("/ProductionUnitTypes/Details/" + UnitContextId(prId) );

        if (sl[1] == "IR")
            return Content("/ItemRoles/Details/" +  RoleContextId(prId) );
       
        // etcetera
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by including the below code just before the $.get() function

`$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});`

It works! Try it :)

Comment: For me it does not.. -1