# window.onpopstate don't work any alert or console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have question for this question
[How to call ajax again when user click back button to go back last webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449981/how-to-call-ajax-again-when-user-click-back-button-to-go-back-last-webpage/54342318#54342318)

I did it step by step but it does not work.

This function don't work

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
    var res = localStorage.getItem('response');         
    success(res);
}
```

I tried to display at least console.log (e), but nothing is displayed in the console

Comment: of course it does work, it's just you are not doing it right, maybe subscribing after the event.

Comment: what subscribing ?

Answer (score 0):

is there anybody here who could explain to me how it should work?
I have same code

```
$.ajax({
        url : ajax_url,
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            sorting : sorting,
            action : 'filterSorting'
        },
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        error : function (responce) {
            console.log(responce);
        },
        success : function (responce) {
            // window.history.pushState({}, '');
            window.localStorage.setItem("response", responce);
            $('#products .row-products').html(responce);


            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.loading').addClass('hide');
                $('.loading').delay(2000).remove();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
    return false;

    window.onpopstate = function (e) {
    var responce = window.localStorage.getItem('response');
    $('#products .row-products').html(responce);
}
```

window.onpopstate it is work only if I click twice on back in browser. Please tell mi why it does not work for the first click back